# Magento 2 is installed but admin login form is missing

Tags: xampp, windows-10, magento2

I have installed magento 2 several times now and I keep getting the same result. 
Of a sparse home screen and no login form for the admin page, only the brown background. 
Front end page

[image]

Admin page (notice the correct brown background but no form, and it is not hidden I did check the dev tools 
[image]

I have looked at the error logs and followed instructions

- https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-white-screen/
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91103/magento-admin-page-white-screen
- https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-1-x/Blank-page-on-admin/td-p/1428

I am running windows 10 and using xampp. The database is created and so are the tables, but they are empty. Does someone know how to fix this? Is it a permission issue?

Comment: I am working on the comments left below, sorry for the delay, I will up you guys with the solution today

Comment: I have downloaded and reinstalled magento server times and diffirent versions as well. the result is the same. I think it has to do with permission errors for folders and despite my best efforts to make the perissions as relaxed as I can it still is not loading properly. I am going to try to install the test data only now and see if that produces a working site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database is empty, i think you need reinstall it.

But first You recommended enable a couple of debugging options:

- php.ini

  - error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
  - display_errors = On
  - log_errors = On
  - error_log = c:\[some.where]\php_errors.log
- Magento 2 (debug/dev) settings

  - app/etc/env.php: MAGE_MODE set to developer ('MAGE_MODE' => 'developer')
  - check permissions (project_root/generated, project_root/var/*)
  - check your htaccess file
  - clear cache from cli

And check your Magento project_root/var/log/system.log file for errors. (and all log files)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Magento again and don't forget to include sample data. Follow the instructions provided on the following page:

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-install-magento-2.html